# Trigger change after items are selected in a multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have a multiple select box:

```
<select id="sel" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="9">Nine</option>
    <option value="10">Ten</option>
</select>
```

To select items, you can hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on individual items.  I want to save the data from this select box after the user is done selecting items.  How can I do that?

I thought of using `setTimeout` and saving 500ms after the `onChange` event is triggered, but I don't know if this is the best idea.

```
$('#sel').change(function(){
    setTimeout(saveData, 500);
});
```

I know I could add a 'Save' button, but I want to save the data on the fly.

What is the best way to save data from a multiple select box on the fly (after the user selects items)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it `onchange`, and after so much time has passed save it like you have, only thing I would change is resetting the `timeout` on each change so it only does it on the final `onchange`.

Something along these lines.

```
var changeTimeout;

$('#sel').change(function(){
    clearTimeout(changeTimeout);
    changeTimeout = setTimeout(function(){saveData()}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: That's a good idea, why didn't I think of that?  I think I need more caffeine.